# Redis expire caching not clear anything

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I set to expire for 'editorial' key one min and caching not deleted from Redis database

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() throws Exception {

    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    redisTemplate.expire("editorial", 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    redisTemplate.expire("s3-files", 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    initRedisSerializer(redisTemplate);
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis dont perform realtime physical delete when key become expired.

Instead, it perform something like passive delete. According to different expire delete strategy, it perform delete operation when needed. You can check it from here (https://www.programmersought.com/article/64021141500/)

But,if u tried to read a expired key, u wont get it.